# JPQL comparasion between MAX(Long) and null

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am trying to select an entity `A` with a Long value `b` and a bunch of other values `c`. I want to get the `A` with the largest `b` value or if no such value exists fall back to getting the `A` where `b` is null.

It seems to me that `MAX(x)` would return null for a Long datatype according to [this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbwa) so I was hoping to do this:

```
SELECT entity FROM A entity
WHERE entity.b = (SELECT MAX(a.b) FROM A a)
AND entity.c = :c
```

This works well when `b` has a defined Long value. When `b` is null however, I get not results. It seems the `=` operator cannot compare NULL values.

I tried using `IS NULL` in an `OR` clause but I only want the entity with the null value if the MAX result is null and the following query returns both the max Long value and the null value:

```
SELECT entity FROM A entity
WHERE (
           (entity.b = (SELECT MAX(a.b) FROM A a))
           (OR entity.b IS NULL)
      )
AND entity.c = :c
```

How can I select my entity that has the largest value `b` or if no `b` is set, get the entity where `b` is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULLS FIRST|LAST` can be used to order the result and then limit the result to 1. Then there is no need to use `MAX(x)`.

Since NULL always comes first and `NULLS LAST` is not supported in my environment I have worked around it using a query like this:

```
SELECT entity FROM A entity
WHERE entity.b = (SELECT MAX(a.b) FROM A a)
AND entity.c = :c
ORDER BY entity.b ASC
```

And some code:

```
try {   
    ...
    List<A> as = q.getResultList();
    result = as.get(as.size() - 1);
catch (NoResultException e) {
    // doo something
}
```

Still very interested in an answer that uses JSQL comparasion though!